# Using CAShapeAnimation Progressively Using Taps iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, progress, cashapelayer

As I tap, I would like a counter to increment to increase the arc size of a circle.

The line should animate to the next size and stay there until the next increment is made (lets say from a tap - that i already measure elsewhere), then animate to the next size etc..

Seee the example below

[image: example]

Here is some code I've found so far...

> _radius = 150;
>
> ```
> CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
> // Make a circular shape
> circle.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 2.0*_radius, 2.0*_radius)
>                                          cornerRadius:_radius].CGPath;
> // Center the shape in self.view
> circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.target.frame)-_radius,
>                               CGRectGetMidY(self.target.frame)-_radius);
>
> // Configure the appearence of the circle
> circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
> circle.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
> circle.lineWidth = 5;
>
> // Add to parent layer
> [self.view.layer addSublayer:circle];...
>
> // Configure animation
> CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
> drawAnimation.duration            = 0.3; // "animate over 10 seconds or so.."
> drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;  // Animate only once..
> drawAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;   // Remain stroked after the animation..
>
> // Animate from no part of the stroke being drawn to the entire stroke being drawn
> drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
> //drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
>
> // Experiment with timing to get the appearence to look the way you want
> drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
>
> // Add the animation to the circle
>
> [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
> ```

Comment: What effect does that code produce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Animating Drawing Values

I've done similar animations in CoreGraphics, so you may want to take a look at that as an alternative if you can't get `CAShapeAnimation` to work for you. I've got a progress view [here](https://github.com/lightdesign/LDProgressView) that has this sort of animation except in a linear fashion.

```
- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)progress {
    self.progressToAnimateTo = progress;
    if (self.animationTimer) {
        [self.animationTimer invalidate];
    }
    self.animationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.008 target:self selector:@selector(incrementAnimatingProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)incrementAnimatingProgress {
    if (_progress >= self.progressToAnimateTo-0.01 && _progress <= self.progressToAnimateTo+0.01) {
        _progress = self.progressToAnimateTo;
        [self.animationTimer invalidate];
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    } else {
        _progress = (_progress < self.progressToAnimateTo) ? _progress + 0.01 : _progress - 0.01;
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

This technique of using another property such as `progressToAnimateTo` and incrementing the `progress` value before redrawing could also be harnessed to then redraw the progress of a circle.

## Resources

I might also add that there are other implementations of what you're doing here. [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) and [EVCircularProgressView](https://github.com/ejvaughan/EVCircularProgressView) have this sort of effect.